# Mysql auto-increment a column with one specific primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Let's say I have a table with following scheme: 
(Note the Post Number column)

```
-- UserID  -- Post Id  -- Post Number*

-- 4       -- 85       -- 1
-- 4       -- 86       -- 2
....
-- 5       -- 9362     -- 1
-- 4       -- 9363     -- 3
```

Is there a way to auto_increment a column independently from all other entries and only respect those with the same primary key?  If so, how would someone implement this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean auto increment the post number?

Comment: I guess the OP wants to increment the Post Number according to UserId column. So basically each UserId will have his own set of PostNumber

Comment: @Paul Karam Yes that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve what you're looking for, you have to use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). There's no other direct way to accomplish this task (I guess).

I did try a fast demo now:

```
Create Table SoQuestion (
  UserId int,
  PostId int,
  PostNumber int null
 );

 CREATE TRIGGER inc_post_num 
 BEFORE INSERT ON SoQuestion
 FOR EACH ROW
 set New.PostNumber = (select num 
                       From (select count(*) as num 
                             from SoQuestion 
                             where UserId = New.UserId) as b) 
                     + 1;


insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (1,1);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (1,10);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (1,20);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (2,1);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (2,10);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (3,1);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (4,1);

select * FROM SoQuestion;
```

And here's the output that I got:

```
UserId | PostId | PostNumber |
==============================  
1      | 1      | 1          |
1      | 10     | 2          |
1      | 20     | 3          |
2      | 1      | 1          |
2      | 10     | 2          |
3      | 1      | 1          |
4      | 1      | 1          |
```

Here's the [demo](https://paiza.io/projects/VE62tgqLlAkcQjp3tYs7vA?language=mysql).

---

After going through the [Auto_Increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) documentation, I found another way to achieve this without using triggers. The idea is about creating an `Auto_Increment` column and add it with another column as `PRIMARY KEY`. In our case it would be `UserId` and the `AUTO_INCREMENT` would be `PostNumber` and they both form the primary key. This is how:

```
Create Table SoQuestion (
  UserId int,
  PostId int,
  PostNumber int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (UserId, PostNumber)
 );

insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (1,1);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (1,10);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (1,20);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (2,1);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (2,10);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (3,1);
insert into SoQuestion (UserId, PostId) Values (4,1);

select * FROM SoQuestion;
```

This would give us the same output that the first way gave:

```
UserId | PostId | PostNumber |
==============================  
1      | 1      | 1          |
1      | 10     | 2          |
1      | 20     | 3          |
2      | 1      | 1          |
2      | 10     | 2          |
3      | 1      | 1          |
4      | 1      | 1          |
```

And here's the [demo](https://paiza.io/projects/UYlO1VgUTS2U99LbL1FrDQ?language=mysql) for the second way.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bug...  If a row is deleted `COUNT(*)` causes trouble.  Instead use `MAX(PostId)`.  But, then it gets messy if there are no entries yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET New.PostId := IFNULL(
      ( SELECT  MAX(PostId)+1
            FROM  SoQuestion
            WHERE  UserId = New.UserId ), 1);
```

This should avoid the bug wherein a `DELETE` messes with `COUNT(*)`.