# Auto-generated value for primary key using prime numbers only

Tags: mysql

I want to make an auto generated value for primary key with prime numbers.

For example, I have this table where `id` is the primary key:

tags_table :

```
   id | name
    ---------
    2  | some_text
    3  | some_text
    5  | some_text
    ...
    997| some_text
```

when ever a new row inserted it will get the next prime number for the `id` .

**is** there a way to achieve this in mysql or any other RDBMS ? if so **how** ?

Comment: use MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland That would give you the next number, not the next **primary** number.

Comment: What to you mean with primary number..

Comment: If this was straightfoward, I think the entirety of modern cryptography would be at risk.

Comment: @RaymondNijland A prime number is a whole number greater than 1 whose only factors are 1 and itself

Comment: he means prime number

Comment: I don’t think there is a way to do this with auto increment you may have to do it manually when inserting by checking the last value entered.

Comment: what code have you written to solve the problem? why do you need this?

Comment: @DanielA.White I have no idea to implement this so I didn't write any , also I need this to use the id in some calculations

Comment: please any one downvote shows the reason to downvote

Comment: I personally didn’t, but people downvoted because you have no code or queries. At least write out what you know and ask for help to turn it into what you want. Or show some research you have done to help people understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712302/6783663) a question on how to change a value during insert. The key is to use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). *This link is used since you have tagged `mysql`*.

You can't make it Auto Increment using only Prime Numbers by design. You have to create the values yourself.

A sample way to do this would be:

```
Create Table PrimeNumberId (
  NormalId int,
  PrimeId int,
  Name varchar(100) null
 );

CREATE TRIGGER inc_prime_id 
BEFORE INSERT ON PrimeNumberId
FOR EACH ROW
# You have to add your logic here to get next Prime Number, then set it like:
set New.PrimeId = #Number#;
```